gitlab ci - cannot use env variable in artifact name
Using a gitlab pipeline that runs a powershell script. The script creates some environment variable that I can access in the script section as $env:MY_VAR.
I would like to use the contents of that variable in the name of the artifact.
But it seems to me that I can only use pipeline-variables there, and not environment-variables.
build-me:
  script:
    - .\scripts\some-powershell.ps1 #creates env var MY_VAR
    - echo $env:MY_VAR   #fine
    
artifacts:
  name: "$env:MY_VAR"    #nope (chatgpt 3.5 says it works. Well, it doesn't)

Using gitlab.com. Tried both $env:MY_VAR and $MY_VAR.
Is there a way to achieve what I want or am I asking the wrong thing?
Thanks

There's open issue about it.
issue
So as I understand, it's a bug. It should work, but it doesnt
